# Django password-reset email shows wrong domain

Tags: django

I've set up a Django project on a Linode server. When I go to `/password_reset`, fill out the form with an email and hit "submit," the address I enter gets a message with a password reset link.

But the subject says "Password reset on Default". The body has the following message:

```
Hello,

You received this email because a request was made to reset the password.


If you requested this, go to the following page and choose a new password: https://127.0.0.1:8000/reset/MQ/4w9-86d9ad84d3320ddcc5a6/

Your username: my.personal@gmail.com

Thank you.
```

How do I set my site's domain or name in the subject? How do I set the correct domain name in the email body?

Comment: did you use django default auth's password reset? `'django.contrib.auth.urls'` this one

Comment: The URLs are default, I just made custom password reset templates

Comment: could you upload your template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Mezzanine. I logged into the `/admin` section. I clicked "Sites," selected "127.0.0.1"; changed the domain name from that to my site's domain, and changed the site name from "Default" to my preferred site name.

Comment: There is not Sites under /admin